# How to use the VIPS dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I have just started learning C# and ASP.NET for my project and i need to use the VIPS(VIsion based Page Segmentation) DLL but i don't know how to go about doing that as im new to C# and ASP.NET.I know how to create and use a simple DLL using C# but then i want to know how to find out the names of the classes and/or functions inside the VIPS DLL and how to use it.I have tried 2 or 3 DLL viewers and disassemblers but the output they gave is in asm format which is very hard to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

VIPS looks like an unmanaged DLL. You'll need to access it from C# using PInvoke.

Since you're new to C# and I would assume .NET in general, you should start by reading here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services